# Python exec() with function definition in a subprocess

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm running several strings with python `exec()` serially like Jupyter Notebook, which means later blocks can access variables defined in previous blocks.

I hope to kill it if a certain block runs longer that 1s, so I execute it with `multiprocess.apply_sync`.

Certainly I maintain `local_namespace` when calling `exec()`, and due to multiprocessing I pass and get back local_namespace with **`multiprocess.Manager`**.

But I found **if there are function definitions in my executed block, the local_namespace becomes None**. Everything works fine if there are no function definitions, or if I call `exec()` in my main process.

Here's the code:

```
import sys
import traceback
import pickle
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool, Manager


def worker(code, namespace):
    # global code
    global_namespace = namespace['global_namespace']
    local_namespace = namespace['local_namespace']
    try:
        exec(code, global_namespace, local_namespace)
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
    # Here I can see the local_namespace becomes None
    pickle.dump(local_namespace, open('local_namespace', 'wb'))

    namespace['global_namespace'] = global_namespace
    namespace['local_namespace'] = local_namespace
    return local_namespace['ans']

def execute_code(code, namespace):
    res = None
    print('input code:\n{}\n*********'.format(code))
    try:
        code_prev_line, code_last_line = tuple(code.strip().rsplit('\n', maxsplit=1))
    except:
        print('exception:', code)
    else:
        code = '{}\nans = {}'.format(code_prev_line, code_last_line)
    print('executing code:\n{}\n********'.format(code))

    with Pool(processes=1) as p:
        result = p.apply_async(worker, (code, namespace))
        try:
            res = result.get(timeout=1)
        except:
            pass
        print('executed result:', res)
        print('local_namespace:', namespace['local_namespace'])
        return res, namespace

if __name__ == '__main__':
# This code leads to bug only in multiprocess
    a = '''
def f():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = x + y
    return z
f()
'''

# This code works fine both in multiprocess and in main process
    a = '''
x = 1
y = 2
x + y
'''
    # main process
    local_namespace = {}
    exec(a, None, local_namespace)
    print('local_namespace:', local_namespace)

    # multiprocess
    with Manager() as manager:
        namespace = {
            'global_namespace': {},
            'local_namespace': {}
        }
        shared_namespace = manager.dict(namespace)
        res, namespace = execute_code(a, shared_namespace)
        # print('local_namespace:', namespace)
```

I tried running code both in main process and in multiprocess, and try code with and without function definitions. Only executing code with function definition in a multiprocess led to bug(local_namespace becomes None after `exec()`)

I found some answers suggesting adding `global f()` and I tried it. It did work. But I cannot understand the reason since I already passed {} as `global_namespace` to `exec`